# Configuring multi-monitor setup in SwayWM on Debian 12 laptop

Tags: debian, multi-monitor, wayland, sway, dock

I'm pretty new to Linux. I'm using Debian 12 on a laptop (and a dock) with the SwayWM wayland compositor. I have 2 external monitors connected to the dock, one landscape (DVI) monitor and another portrait (VGA) monitor.

How could I:

- Change the arrangement and rotation of the monitors
- Set the background of any monitor to an image
- Have persistence of everything when I undock and dock again

Using Xubuntu, I can easily do everything using Xfce4 Display Settings and xfdesktop. But how do I do the aforementioned in Sway? (I don't need a GUI though since I'm rarely gonna change anything)

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display configuration on sway is done via `swaymsg`:

```
$ swaymsg output HDMI-A-1 mode 1280x720 position 0,0
```

`swaymsg` is a tool to get info on and send commands to the running `sway` process. For more info see `man swaymsg`, `man sway`, `man sway.5`, and `man sway-output.5`.

---

Background/wallpaper is likewise handled with `swaymsg`:

```
$ output DisplayPort-0 bg /home/user/Pictures/mybackground.png fill
```

Full list of options in `man sway-output.5`.

---

Persistence for background image, layout, hotkeys, etc. can simply be added or modified in `~/.config/sway/config`, and persistence of display configuration there is [`kanshi`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/kanshi/kanshi.1.en.html).

1. Install `kanshi`
2. Create one or more profiles
3. Create a `kanshi` user service (see [sway](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Sway#Manage_Sway-specific_daemons_with_systemd) on the arch wiki)

With `kanshi` running as a user service, it will respond to monitor hotplug events by applying a profile based on which monitors are connected. For example, you could use it on a laptop and have a "solo" profile that only configure the internal display, and a "docked" profile that includes a secondary monitor, configured in any arrangement and orientation you wish. The [`kanshi(5`)](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/kanshi/kanshi.5.en.html) configuration documentation is pretty sparse, though easy enough to sort out by running a few queries, for instance:

```
$ swaymsg -t get_outputs 
Output HDMI-A-1 'LG Electronics LG SIGNAGE 0x00000101' (focused)
  Current mode: 1920x1080 @ 60.000 Hz
  Position: 0,0
  Scale factor: 1.000000
  Scale filter: nearest
  Subpixel hinting: unknown
  Transform: normal
  Workspace: 1
  Max render time: off
  Adaptive sync: disabled
  Available modes:
    1920x1080 @ 60.000 Hz
    1920x1080 @ 60.000 Hz
    1920x1080 @ 60.000 Hz (16:9)
    1920x1080 @ 50.000 Hz
    1920x1080 @ 50.000 Hz (16:9)
    1280x1024 @ 60.020 Hz
    1280x960 @ 60.000 Hz
    1280x720 @ 60.000 Hz
    1280x720 @ 60.000 Hz (16:9)
    1280x720 @ 50.000 Hz (16:9)
    1024x768 @ 60.004 Hz
    800x600 @ 60.317 Hz
    720x576 @ 50.000 Hz (16:9)
    720x576 @ 50.000 Hz (4:3)
    720x480 @ 59.940 Hz (16:9)
    720x480 @ 59.940 Hz (4:3)
```

```
$ cat .config/kanshi/config
profile myprofile {
        output 'LG Electronics LG SIGNAGE 0x00000101' mode 1920x1080@60 position 0,0
}

profile someotherprofile {
        output 'LG Electronics LG SIGNAGE 0x00000101' mode 1920x1080@60 position 0,0
        output HDMI-A-2 mode 1920x1080@60 position 1920,0
}
```